# program for finding the minimum value in an array of integersi(in C) won't compile

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to come up with a program that reads in numbers from the command line, turns the argv array into integers, and then finds the smallest integer in the array of those integers. 
Below is my code for this program, can anyone help me out?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int *integerizeArgs(int, char **);
int *findMin(int, int *);

int *integerizeArgs(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int i = 0;
        int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * (argc-1));
        for(i= 1; i < argc; ++i){
                a[i-1] = atoi(argv[1]);
                return a;
        }
return 0;
}


int *findMin(int itemCount, int *a) {
        int i, smallest = a[0];
        for (i=0; i < itemCount; i++) {
                if(a[i] < smallest) {
                        smallest = a[i];
                        return smallest;
                        }
                return 0;
        }
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
        int *a = integerizeArgs(argc, argv);
        int b = findMin(argc, a[0]);
        printf("%d", b);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm certain if this doesn't compile a host of error messages report that condition. How about putting them in your question? From what i see immediately the return type should be `int`, not `int*` for `findMin`. And that `return smallest` doesn't really belong there in the first place. It belongs outside the loop.

Comment: You say it doesn't compile.  Ok, so which error message are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: This code [compiled](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/pXnE7tV83wcK8lGe) with warnings and got Segmentation Fault.

Comment: Code is now compiling, but is returning 0 instead of the smallest command line integer.

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* by using value in buffer allocated via `malloc()` and not initialized in the new code.

Comment: You have a bad return inside the for loop of `integerizeArgs`. (What were you thinking there?) Otherwise it ought to work. Delete the first `return a;`.

Comment: @Gene Did that, program is still returning zero. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. (And I just had a brain fart including the return statement in the loop and the function).

Comment: *it won't compile* is absolutely useless information unless you include the error message you received from  the compiler. You have that information on the screen right in front of your face - there is absolutely no  excuse for not including it in  your question. You're asking for our **free help** to solve **your problem**; the very least you can do is give us the information you *already have* right in front of your eyes. I rolled back your edit; you can't change the question's meaning after you';ve received answers to the original question. If you have a new problem, post a new question.

Comment: @KenWhite sorry man, forgot to include my compiling errors. They didn't make sense to me, so I thought it'd be worthless to include them.

Comment: Clearly the compiler doesn't produce nonsense. The error messages convey useful information. If you had all the answers, you wouldn't be asking a question here. But you are, because you're expecting people here to know more than you and be able to help. Common sense should tell you that those same people would also have a better understanding of those compiler errors as well. As I said, there's no excuse for not including them (and you **still** have not edited to do so).

Comment: Well, I updated my code to what the comments told me to do and I'm not getting any compiling errors, all I'm getting now is the first integer in the command line returned, when it should be the smallest integer in the command line returned to standard output. But because you won't let me edit my comment to say that, I cannot. Again, now I'm not getting compiler errors anymore, just the wrong integer returned to me.

Comment: findmin() has a pointer type definition, but returns a scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write proper code.

- You should check if `malloc()` was successful.
- Be careful for typo. `argv[1]` is not as reasonable as `argv[i]` here.
- Do not use `return;` when you don't want to return from the function.
- Use proper type. Distinguish between "normal" integers and pointers.
- Be careful for [off-by-one error](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/193.html).
  In this case, `argc-1` elements are allocated, not `argc` elements.
- You should free whatever you allocated.

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int *integerizeArgs(int, char **);
int findMin(int, int *);

int *integerizeArgs(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int i = 0;
        int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * (argc-1));
        if (a == NULL){ /* add error check */
                perror("malloc");
                exit(1);
        }
        for(i= 1; i < argc; ++i){
                a[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]); /* convert each arguments instead of only the first one */
                /* don't return when the process is not done */
        }
        return a; /* return the result */
}

/* use proper return type */
int findMin(int itemCount, int *a) {
        int i, smallest = a[0];
        for (i=0; i < itemCount; i++) {
                if(a[i] < smallest) {
                        smallest = a[i];
                        /* don't return when the process is not done */
                }
                /* don't return when the process is not done */
        }
        return smallest; /* return the result */
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
        int *a = integerizeArgs(argc, argv);
        /* pass the (pointer to) the array instead of the first element of the array (&a[0] is also OK) */
        /* pass correct itemCount (there are argc-1 items because the first argument typically is the command) */
        int b = findMin(argc - 1, a);
        printf("%d", b);
        free(a); /* free whatever you allocated */
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Write proper code." Would you be so kind as to elaborate upon that?

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks a bunch man. I'm a bit confused as to why I have to add an error check for malloc, as I thought that if there's no memory to allocate, the program simply just ignores it and doesn't try to allocate any memory. But thanks again, I kept on forgetting argc -1 is showing the variables and not the program name.

Comment: @Seb He was probably referring to me not properly using the return type. I just forgot that it's used at the end of a function, not the end of a loop.

Comment: @Seb You mean the comments in the code isn't enough?

Comment: @MikeCAT Not only are the comments in your code not enough, but they're examples of what not to do with comments; they are examples of what *proper code* should **not** look like. Comments shouldn't be used to describe *what* code does because the code describes what the code does, which makes the comments redundant and easily desynchronised during maintenance. Whenever I see a comment that describes what code does, I think "I bet this comment is lying to me"... and half the time I'm not disappointed.

Comment: Actually your code is wrong, it takes in the first number from the command line, not the smallest.

Comment: I'm an idiot, forgot to change atoi(argv[1]) to argv[i]. Again, thanks so much. Your comments and such were really helpful in telling me why I was wrong with my code. I'm still a bit confused with malloc but everything else makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with this code. Such significant misunderstandings would tend to elude to the point that your resources aren't working for you. Have you considered trying other resources?

If you don't yet understand the basics of procedural programming, I recommend learning a different language first. Unfortunately I haven't come across a decent C programming book that teaches both procedural programming in general and C programming. The only books I know of seem to require that you already understand procedural programming. I'll try to help a bit with that with this post.

I can highly recommend K&R 2E, providing you've understood the procedural programming basics first; remember to do the exercises as you encounter them as they're a valuable part of the learning experience.

---

You seem to be quite confused about the effect upon the flow of execution caused by `return`, `for` and `if`. C is a procedural language, meaning it has a structure similar to a recipe in a cookbook (a *procedure*), for example.

Okay, that's grossly over-simplified, but if you think of steps like "preheat the oven to 180C (described in page 42)" and "caramelise the onion" as though they are separate procedures then we can establish a use for keywords like `return`, `for` and `if`, so bear with me.

As you turn to page 42 you might notice the procedure is simple but disjoint from the recipe, something like this:

- Ensure the oven is empty, and if necessary install an oven thermometer onto the front of one of the racks.
- **`if`** the oven is a gas oven:

  - Strike a match.
  - Kneel in front of the oven, and turn the knob to the appropriate temperature.
  - Bring the lit match into contact with the gas stream, keeping your fingers well clear of the gas stream at all times.
- **`else`** turn the knob to the appropriate temperature.
- Close the oven.
- **`for`** the duration beginning when you close the oven and ending when the thermometer reaches the appropriate value, periodically check the thermometer
- **`return`** to the previous procedure.

Here, the words `if` and `else` are clearly meant to ensure that you choose the appropriate path for your oven. The same goes for your computer. You're telling it to choose which one of the paths based on the condition in your code.

The `return` keyword is used to tell you that the procedure is over, and you should resume the procedure you were using before.

There is a loop embedded into the procedure, too. That could be expressed using `for` language, i.e. "for the duration beginning when you close the oven and ending when the thermometer reaches the appropriate value, periodically check the thermometer" would loosely translate to something like:

```
close(oven);
for (actual_temp = check_temp(oven); actual_temp < desired_temp; actual_temp = check_temp(oven)) {
    sleep(15 minutes);
}
```

---

Recipes are easy to understand because they're written in natural language. Computer programs, however, aren't. Programming languages have idioms that aren't so commonly used in natural language, such as variable scope and memory location, so it's important to use those idioms consistently.

I recommend designing software as though it's meant to fit in with the environment. I can see you've given that some thought by forwarding `argc` and `argv` (or its translated equivalent) to each of your functions, but a deeper analysis of the environment is required.

It goes against the grain for a function to perform allocation and expect the caller to perform cleanup for that allocation. If you analyse the example set by the C standard library, the only functions that allocate memory are allocation functions, thread creation and file creation. Everything else lets the caller choose how memory is allocated. Thus, your `integerizeArgs` function should probably be refactored:

```
int *integerize_arguments(int *destination, char **source, size_t length) {
    for (size_t x = 0; x < length; x++) {
        if (sscanf(source[x], "%d", &destination[x]) != 1) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return destination;
}
```

Did you notice how closely this resembles `memcpy`, for example? Using this pattern the caller can choose what kind of allocation the array should have, which is very nice for maintenance should you decide you don't need `malloc`.

Also notice how I used `size_t` for index variables. This is important because it doesn't usually make sense to allow negative numbers for arrays.

---

As for your `findMin` function, the best advice I can give there is to think about the procedural language we discussed earlier. I don't think the instructions you're giving your computer are the same instructions you have in your head. If they are, they don't make sense and you might need to run through that procedure a few times by hand to see what's going wrong.

- Unless the caller (`main`, in this case) needs to know the address of the minimum value, `findMin` doesn't need to return `int *`; it should return `int` instead. If, on the other hand, `main` needs to know where the minimum value is located, then your algorithm needs to be adapted because you're currently not storing that position in your logic.
- As covered by MikeCAT, you shouldn't be `return`ing to the previous procedure until you've inspected the entire array. Hence your `return smallest;` should be *below* the `for` loop.

---

This post is getting quite lengthy, kind of turning into a book of it's own... so I'll wrap up here, and recommend in summary that you purchase a book about programming.